# Does the force kill command (kill -9) in linux cleanup the dynamically allocated memory with new operator in C++ application?

Tags: c++, linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, virtual-memory

I have a C++ application to be run on Oracle Linux OS.

Consider, I have created few objects with `new` operator. Though I have used delete operator to deallocate it, but the force kill command would not reach this implementation.

But, if I force kill (`kill -9`) the process, will the dynamically allocated memory (using `new` operator) be de-allocated by the operating system? As I am not able to find the straightforward answer to this, I would like to have some information.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i'd rather be worried about resources that are not just memory, which are not released properly when destructors are not called. Memory isnt the problem when the process is killed

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does the Unix kill command ensure that dynamically allocated memory will return properly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/389927/does-the-unix-kill-command-ensure-that-dynamically-allocated-memory-will-return)

Answer (score 4):

> But, if I force kill (`kill -9`) the process, will the dynamically allocated memory (using `new` operator) be de-allocated by the operating system?

Memory is tied to a process through the virtual memory system and the memory management unit (MMU). Thus yes, all memory (not just the one allocated through `new`) will be freed.

Exceptions to this are global inter-process communication (IPC) resources like shared memory, cached files, etc.

Comment: Is this dynamic memory cleanup taken care in older versions of Linux flavors? Or are there any specific Linux/Unix flavors that take care of dynamic memory cleanup?As I can see people saying that these are handled in newer versions of OS.

Comment: @VijaykumarAinapur Linux has always required an MMU and performed this clean up. Virtually all operating systems except specialized ones that you would know if you used them do process isolation and use virtual memory. Perhaps someone, somewhere, has patched the official kernel to avoid an MMU, nothing is impossible, but again: you would know if you were using it.

Answer (score 4):

When a process dies by whatever means, all process resources including memory and file objects are cleaned up by the kernel. When you kill a process it stops running immediately so no cleanup code including destuctors is are run. So yes all memory is deallocated but is happens at a much lower level than heaps and stacks.